# NSInternalInconsistencyException using FrontBoard.framework --> FBProcessManager.h --> method of sharedInstance

Tags: ios

When I use iOS PrivateFramework
**FrontBoard.framework** --> **FBProcessManager.h** --> method of `sharedInstance`, I have problems:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FBProcessManager cannot
>   be initialized before calling FBSystemAppMain()'

This is my code：

```
NSBundle *b = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoard.framework"];
BOOL success = [b load];
NSLog(@"%d",success);
Class FBProcessManager = NSClassFromString(@"FBProcessManager");
id manager = [FBProcessManager valueForKey:@"sharedInstance"];
```

Comment: Did you try calling `FBSystemAppMain()`?

Comment: I tried to call, but didn't find it.How to calling FBSystemAppMain( )?

Comment: Try putting `FBSystemAppMain()` below your `NSLog()`.

Comment: FrontBoard.framework is a private frameworks , I can't call it.I scan the iOS -runtime-header , but I don't find FBSystemAppMain.

Comment: What exactly is this framework? Do you have an API?

Comment: I have. https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS9-Runtime-Headers. You can have a try

Comment: This seems to be a private framework, not intended for use by Apple.

Comment: @BensonTommy is you goal to get list of processes?

Comment: @Visput Yes,I find all possible ways in iOS9,but none of them work.

Answer (score 1):

in iOS9,Apple has closed some privacy gaps that allowed Apps to detect which other Apps were installed on the device.

sysctl() was modified to no longer allow sandboxed Apps to retrieve information about other running processes.

So I think the private framework FrontBoard(which we can use to retrieve process tables before)is also on the privacy gaps fixing list.You could read more on this [link](https://nabla-c0d3.github.io/blog/2015/06/16/ios9-security-privacy/).

Comment: if you are trying access all installed applications, this can be achieved using LSApplicationWorkspace and accessing the 'defaultWorkspace' and the 'allApplications' property.  see here: https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/LSApplicationWorkspace.h